# How to transfer information from one IBAction to another

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

The code should work as follows: On one View I click tag button and `tagButtonPressed` IBAction should set `tag` variable to `sender.tag` of the tag button. It works well. Then user should click 'send' button and `sharePressed` IBAction should use the `tag` variable which equals to `sender.tag` of the 'tag' button, and print the updated value of `tag` variable. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
import UIKit

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    var tag : Int = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var shareTextField: UITextView!


    @IBAction func tagButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         tag = sender.tag // lets say sender.tag = 4
         print(tag) // It prints 4
    }

    @IBAction func sharePressed(_ sender: Any) {
         print(tag) // it prints 1 and i want it to print also 4
    }

}
```

Comment: So you're expecting that after the tagButtonPressed(), the self.tag value should be updated, that when the sharePressed() function is called, you'll get the updated value which is 4. Correct?

Comment: Sure, I want to press tagButtonPressed() first which sets the 'tag' value to for example '4' and then press sharePressed() which should use updated value of 'tag' variable which is 4.

Comment: And you're getting a wrong value, which is the default, 1?

Comment: Thats right. // By the way I deleted some of the code to clarify the problem more.

Comment: That should work, no brainer. Add a didSet to your var tag. You can solve that easily. There must be another function that sets your self.tag variable. ```var tag : Int = 1 {
        didSet {
            print("SET!!!: \(self.tag)")
        }
    }``` Replace your var tag... with this code, and you'll see if the self.tag has been set by N-value.

Comment: Okay in the console I get: SET!!!: 4 <break line> 1. So it looks like variable 'tag' is set to 4 but somehow the other IBAction still uses the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Somewhere else (not shown) you're re-setting the tag value to 1.

Comment: Yeah, now I know where the mistake was. I created two view controllers of class MessageView controllers thinking that they will be the same class. The button which sends 'tag' was also a segue which was pushing another VC on the top. As I realized that is how you create two instances of the same class, and I have to pass data between them. I thought I can avoid it this way, but I have to use 'prepare for segue'. Feel free to tell me if there is any easier way to pass data forwards, or how to add two views to one view controller file.

Comment: No, I think you should have two view controllers, if the functions on each are different, or two instances of the same, if the functions are the same, and data types are the same, but you need to operate on different data. You can just declare a variable on one VC and if you store an instance to it, access said variable normally